# Material components not using color accent declared in theme

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, material-components

My main app theme parent is MaterialComponents theme. I changed the colors, but material components (MaterialButton, InputLayout, EditText) are not using my accent color (they are using some blue color, my declared Accent color is Teal) 
What is the issue? How is the best way to deal with theming Material Components?

My main theme:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Edit:
Changing theme to Theme.MaterialComponents.Bridge is not solving that problem.

Comment: is your `@color/colorPrimary` & `@color/colorPrimaryDark` are blue?

Comment: When using MaterialComponents shouldn't you use MaterialButton, MaterialXxx insteadof Button, Xxx?

Comment: Sory, I wasn't clear.
My Color Accent is Teal.
I am using Material Components: Material Buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in my case was a different `styles.xml` declared for the specific API. I made a mistake in it, and when testing, that other `values-v21/styles.xml` was applied before `styles.xml`.

So long story short, check if the mistake is not present in other variants. I declared that variant wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you should try to use `colorSecondary` instead of `colorAccent`:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Original AppCompat attributes. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

This works for me

Answer (score 1):

For those, trying to use a theme that inherits from `Theme.MaterialComponents.*` please also keep in mind not to use a regular `Button` class but `com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton` instead.

Instead of:

```
<Button
  (...)
  style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button" />
```

Make sure to use:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
  (...)
  style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button" />
```

Been there. Nothing to be ashamed of. :)

Answer (score 0):

Inherit your app theme from `Theme.AppCompat` like:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
</style>
```

Note that dark or light theme is upon you but you need to extend `Theme.AppCompat`.

Comment: Do You mean that I should use that theme and declare missing attributes?
Because that theme don't have all attributes for Material Components.

Comment: Yes, all material components use the colors declared in your app theme but it need to be inherited from `Theme.AppCompat` where Android is looking for the theme colors like `colorAccent` or `colorPrimary`. But don't forget to use your declared theme in AndroidManifest like: `<application android:theme="@style/AppTheme">`

Comment: Okay, I will try this approach and give feedback :)

Comment: this does not work if you are actually using MaterialComponents. they depend on inheriting from the MaterialComponents theme.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your styles.xml like this :

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

If this works, let me know

Edit : Try following this link for setting up material components https://medium.com/@pedromassango/android-material-design-components-setup-google-i-o18-part-1-8894f315b5e

Comment: It is not working, I was trying few variants, as well as Bridge variants.
I think I need to override more attributes